# How do I make command line arguments with a hyphen (-) show up as non-optional in python v2.7?

Tags: python-2.7, argparse

I have the following python script

```
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Process controller.py arguments')
parser.add_argument("-b", help='Build number, e.g., 1234')
args = vars(parser.parse_args())
```

When I run it I get...

```
$ python CommandLineParser.py -h
usage: CommandLineParser.py [-h] [-b B]

Process controller.py arguments

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit
  -b B        Build number, e.g., 1234
```

How do I make the "-b" show up as a "non-optional" argument (because it's NOT!). As an added bonus, how do I rid of the uppercase "B" after it? Thanks!

Comment: From the argparse documentation: "Note Required options are generally considered bad form because users expect options to be optional, and thus they should be avoided when possible."  The default help groupings are `positionals` and `optionals`.  See the section on `argument groups`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to set [required](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#required) to `True` and [metavar](http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#metavar) (it's responsible for `B`) to `''`:

```
parser.add_argument("-b", help='Build number, e.g., 1234', required=True, metavar='')
```

Actually, you will still see your `required` argument as optional if run your script in a `help` mode. This is because of a bug: [argparse required arguments displayed under "optional arguments"](http://bugs.python.org/issue9694):

> The argparse module lists required args as optional in the default
>   help message.

There are also some workarounds suggested, but I like this one more: add your own `required arguments` group:

```
required_group = parser.add_argument_group('required arguments')
required_group.add_argument("-b", help='Build number, e.g., 1234', required=True, metavar='')
```

Then, you will see this on a command-line:

```
$ python test.py -h
usage: test.py [-h] -b

Process controller.py arguments

optional arguments:
  -h, --help  show this help message and exit

required arguments:
  -b          Build number, e.g., 1234
```

Comment: Thanks. If I add a metavar='--build' for example, and run the command python test.py --build 1234, it complains about requiring -b. Isn't what the metavar provides? If not how can I enable a --build option as sysnonym for -b option?

Comment: `metavar` is used in help messages, it's a way of referring to the argument. To make `--build` work as `-b`, try this: `required_group.add_argument("-b", "--build", help='Build number, e.g., 1234', required=True, metavar='')`

Comment: This worked. But now if I do args = vars(parser.parse_args()), and someVar = args['b'], I get a KeyError: 'b' failure?

Comment: I fixed it, I simply have to use args['build']

Comment: When you specify both a short optionals string `-b` and a long one `--build`, the long one (minums the `--`) is used as the `dest` name in the returned Namespace.  You can change that with a `dest` parameter.  Without the long name, the short one is used as the `dest`.

Answer (score 0):

Please use the required keyword when adding it to the argparse: http://docs.python.org/2/library/argparse.html#sub-commands

```
parser.add_argument("-b", help='Build number, e.g., 1234', required=True)
```